# Maximal number of smallest circuits in a matroid

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory, extremal-combinatorics, matroid-theory

It is known (see [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1210.6342) for example) that, in a simple graph of odd genus $g$ with $n$ vertices and $m$ edges, the number of cycles of lenght $g$ is at most $\frac{n(m-n+1)}{g}$.

Since this can be be phrased only in terms of circuits and matroid properties (when the graph is connected, we can recover $n$ as the rank of the matroid plus one), I was wondering is this result could be extended to any matroid. More precisey, is it true that, for any matroid of size $m$, rank $r$ and odd genus $g$, the number of circuits of size $g$ is at most $\frac{(r+1)(m-r)}{g}$?

If no, are there some weaker similar bounds on the number of circuits of size $g$?

If yes, what can we say about the equality case? In the case of graphs, it is reached for the Moore graphs. Are there new non-graphical matroids reaching the equality?

Comment: If you leave the world of graphical matroids, no such small bound can hold. The number of shortest circuits in a uniform matroid $U_{m,r}$ is $\binom{m}{r+1}$.

Comment: Oh, you're right... I was hoping that this bound could have given some matroid theoritic version of Moore graphs, but this probably can't work